# A weird-looking fish with a shield

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ichthyology, marine-biology

I found this photo in a [local news page](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=628341997202095&set=a.370464582989839.74242.113791238657176&type=1&theater). The page claims that this fish is a new species that was found by a Malaysian fisherman. Is this true or is it a known fish and already has a name?

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the link to the local news website? It looks like an April Fish ;)

Comment: @Remi.b updated the question with the link. It is in Arabic anyway :) hope you can understand the language. You can use google translate if you don't.

Comment: BTW, Alarabiya.Net is a well known well trusted news source in the Middle East.

Comment: Found a similar article in an English website: http://www.muldersworld.com/photo.asp?id=7644

Comment: There are tons of similar article on this fish. [Here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2488383/Is-terrifying-sea-creature-caught-Mystery-species-fearsome-tusk-like-spikes-spines-body-Borneo.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490), [here](http://www.reefs.com/blog/2013/11/08/mystery-armored-fish-turns-borneo/) and [here](http://www.ibtimes.com/bizarre-armor-fish-caught-south-china-sea-remains-unidentified-1458992)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The front part of the fish looks like part of the cranium of a fish. I'd bet that the tusks have been "made" by removing some bones in the middle.

Well, after having looked at the links given by Remi.b, it seems that it's not even necessary to remove bones. This is probably a Peristediidae.

You can find some images on [fishbase](http://www.fishbase.org/identification/specieslist.php?famcode=581&areacode=)

Comment: blood-mark in mouth-portion

Comment: Aww I missed the old answer also contained the taxonomic designation in the second paragraph. sorry for that.

Answer (score 28):

This is a species in the [**Peristediidae**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armored_searobin) family, commonly called **armored searobins** or **armored gurnards**.

> found in deep waters around the world, with most species in tropical regions. They are related to the searobins in the family Triglidae, and some authorities classify them in that family,[2][3] but they are encased in heavy scales with prominent spines. They have prominent and often elaborate barbels on their chins.

Characteristics of Peristediidae [[Source](http://www.academia.edu/4178147/A_new_species_of_Satyrichthys_Teleostei_Peristediidae_from_the_Maldives_Archipelago_Indian_Ocean_)]:

> The scorpaeniform family Peristediidae (armored sea robins) is characterized by (1) a body entirely enclosed by four rows of spinous bony plates (scutes) on each side; (2) a large bony head with spines and ridges; (3) each first infraorbital (lachrymal) anteriorly extending in distinct rostral projections; (4) barbels on the lower jaw, and (5)pectoral fins with the two ventral most fin rays free and enlarged (Miller 1974; Miller & Richards 2002; Richards 1984, 1999; Kawai 2008, 2013)

Specifically, this looks similar to other species in the genus [*Satyrichthys*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyrichthys).

[image: Armored Gurnard]

<sup>*Satyrichthys welchi* (Source: [Taiwan Biodiversity Informaiton Facility](http://eoldata.taibif.tw/files/eoldata/imagecache/data_object_image/images/39/NMMSTP01655_0.jpg))</sup>

According to [Pogoreutz et al. 2013](http://www.academia.edu/4178147/A_new_species_of_Satyrichthys_Teleostei_Peristediidae_from_the_Maldives_Archipelago_Indian_Ocean_):

> The genus Satyrichthys is diagnosed as follows: (1) no teeth in upper and lower jaws; (2) lateral margin of the head smooth; (3) the ventral row of bony plates on caudal peduncle extending posteriorly, separating the posterior bony plates of the lower lateral series; (4) only the posterior lip and chin barbels branched, and (5) fewer than 20 soft rays in dorsal and anal fin (Kawai 2008, 2013).

> An important character in separating species of the genus
> *Satyrichthys* is the number of lip and chin barbels (Miller 1964, Kawai 2008, 2013)

One similar looking species is [***Satyrichthys welchi***](http://www.fishbase.org/summary/11665) (the **Robust armoured-gurnard**) [pictured above] found in the South China sea:

[image: Range Map]

<sup>Source: [AquaMaps](http://www.aquamaps.org/receive.php?type_of_map=regular)</sup>

According to [FishBase](http://www.fishbase.org/summary/11665), here are some characteristics of ***Satyrichthys welchi***:

- Dorsal spines (total): 7
- Dorsal soft rays (total): 17
- Anal spines: 0
- Anal soft rays: 18

Comment: @AlwaysConfused thanks a lot for the bounty! Glad you appreciated the answer! You should Youtube the family -- some species walk on barbs like they're tiny legs! :D

Comment: I also want to know about the 2 eye-like objects on the head-portion at back  (shown) side. Are the eyes? or nostrils? or something else? And also, is its mouth present at the lower (frontal) portion? and is there any advantage/function of 2 protruding portion beside mouth region.